# Mousemove function on a d3.js topojson county/state map - Hold click to select multiple counties

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

Utilizing Mike Bostocks US Counties bl.ock: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4122298.

The goal is to create a mousemove function that during the event the mousemove will highlight all counties selected. The current example only highlights using `:hover` and doesn't preserve the selection.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.counties :hover {
  fill: red;
}

.county-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var path = d3.geoPath();

d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "county-borders")
      .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));
});

</script>
```

Comment: So you want all countries you hovered to stay red, is that right? A mouse trace?

Comment: @undko Yes, that's correct. I haven't heard that term used before but that is essentially the goal. As long as a mousedown then it will trace the mouse movement.

Comment: I should have put "mouse trace" in quotes as it‘s my personal term for it (not even being native speaker :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my snippet - that‘s what I understood. You need to use JavaScript event and classes since CSS  can‘t change state.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var path = d3.geoPath();

d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path);

  // the following block is new, adding JS events
  let hoverEnabled = false;
  svg.on('mousedown', x => hoverEnabled = true)
    .on('mouseup', x => hoverEnabled = false)
  svg.selectAll('.counties path').on('mouseover', function() {
    if (hoverEnabled) {
      this.classList.add('hovered');
    }
  });
  
  svg.append("path")
     .attr("class", "county-borders")
    .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));
});
```

```css
/* paths with class "hovered" need to be selected here, too */
.counties .hovered, .counties :hover {
  fill: red;
}

.county-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked great. Better than what I had been stumbling through. Thanks for your help! I'm hoping I can write the code to remove the color when "unclicked" myself. Thank you!

Comment: so I'm back again. Without telling me the answer, does the code you provided make it easy to cook in the idea of clicking on an already clicked county and essentially "unclick" it?

Comment: Welcome back! I see three possibilities to "unclick" counties: **1.** If the county that was target of your `mousedown` event had class `hovered` before then remove that class from any county on your way until you release mouse button, add that class otherwise (again to all counties). **2.** Don‘t mind about first county, just invert/toggle all counties on the way **3.** Remove `mousedown` and change existing behavior so that all counties need a click to be toggled, at any time. All three possibilities are doable without major code changes.

Comment: I know this question is old, but I needed this info, but also want to understand what is going on. Can you explain why your added snippet works IF it is inside the d3.json function call, but not outside. Also comment on why you need a selectAll? Maybe just explain what each selectAll statement is selecting? Is it all counties, or is all lines that make up a county?